# isc dhcp server static address allocation

Tags: linux, dhcp-server

I have a server with several network interfaces that are combined in bridge, because all clients should be in same subnet. How should I configure isc-dhcp-server to lease static ip addres to each network interface?
For example:
eth0 - 192.168.1.10 
eth1 - 192.168.1.11
eth2 - 192.168.1.12

Each network interface have only one client (no switch and hub are plugged)

Comment: Why do you think each of those interfaces needs its own IP address to begin with?

Comment: There are several client types (modules) and each network interface is assigned a specific type of module. Modules need to communicate to each other and jnly way to determinate module type is network interface to which it is connected. Server leases IP address to each module and also works as DNS to each module. This need to module to know how to communicate to other modues.

Comment: But that doesn't really go together with all interfaces being bridged into one. Is the DHCP service running _on_ this server?

Comment: Yes, DHCP service running on this server. What do you mean?

Comment: You simply associate each IP address with the cards MAC address.

Comment: I don't know module MAC address.